# Android: Custom collation in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, collation

Is there a way of getting SQLite on Android to use a custom collation routine?

I'm aware of [SQLite's C interface to do this](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/c3ref/create_collation.html), so I guess I could do it by writing C code for building with the NDK, but I'd really prefer a way to do it at a higher level.

I need to arrange things so that the text `B-9` is sorted before `B-29`, for example. The default alphabetical sort gets them the wrong way round.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am pretty sure that there is no way to do this in Android.

My suggestion would be to have a custom column used for ordering where you insert the value in a modified way that gets sorted as you wish.

In your case you could insert B-9 as B-09 or B-00....09 depending on the max value.