# how to select 5.0.0.13 not 5.0.0.2 in sqlite(I want 5.0.0.13 > 5.0.0.2)

Tags: sqlite

There are two data in Sqlite DB

```
5.0.0.13
5.0.0.2
```

What I want is 5.0.0.13

My data rule is .13 bigger than .2, just like 13 > 2

but if I select max(version), it return 5.0.0.2

How could I select 5.0.0.13 ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Custom collation in SQLite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128834/android-custom-collation-in-sqlite)

Comment: Sorry, my close-as-duplicate vote was perhaps a bit hasty, since you didn't specify Android in your question.

Comment: It's a good idea change 2 to 02!

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own [collation rules](http://www.hwaci.com/sw/sqlite/c3ref/create_collation.html) using the C API.