# How to create a collation in SQLite in an Android app?

Tags: android, sqlite, testing, collation

I am trying to emulate following statements in my Android App:

```
db collate {"""} [list string compare -nocase]

do_execsql_test 6.5 {
  PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
  CREATE TABLE p1(a PRIMARY KEY COLLATE '"""');
  CREATE TABLE c1(x, y REFERENCES p1);
} {}
```

Refer commit in SQLite code base: https://www.sqlite.org/src/info/eddc05e7bb31fae7

I am not sure about how to create a collation named """ as mentioned in above code. Is it even possible to do in an Android app?

Related question: [Android: Custom collation in SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8128834/android-custom-collation-in-sqlite)

Comment: Hey, were you able to achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android SQLite Java API does not expose the [functions for creating collation sequences](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_collation.html). To do so in an Android app you'll have to work with the NDK and sqlite C library.

(I'm not sure what you're really trying to achieve by running sqlite library internal tests in an app.)

Comment: Can you suggest me how to create the above specific collation in NDK? I have a strange requirement to do the same thing (db collate {"""} [list string compare -nocase]). I don't have much clarity on what 'list string compare -nocase' translates to in terms of a SQLite collation. Does it mean that while comparing data in a column, case should be ignored?